# Does a Firestore snapshot listener return to undo a latency-compensated return if a write fails?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

If a write is made to Firestore and the UI relies on the latency-compensated return (from a snapshot listener) to move the user forward and that write ends up failing, does that failure invoke the snapshot listener to return immediately with data that undoes the now-incorrect latency-compensated return from the failed write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the write of a document fails, then a listener on that document will see the document removed.  The timestamp won't matter at all since the document is no longer present.

Comment: I should have clarified, the write is an update to an existing document. If that update fails, does that document's listener return immediately to undo the latency-compensated update?

Comment: Yes, the listener will be delivered an updated document with its original values.